# Can you get the value of "old rip at" in a GDB script?

Tags: x86, gdb

I am writing a script to automate a gdb task and I was wondering if this value can be obtained to be used in a gdb expression (like old-rip-at - rsp to get its offset, etc) ? ("old rip at" is displayed at the end of info frame and contains the position on the stack of old rip)

Comment: What do you mean with "old rip"?

Comment: @ssbssa well it's displayed when you do "info frame", old rip is the saved PC(the adress to return to after function finishes), and "old rip at" is the adress on the stack of it.

Comment: So you mean the `$rip` value after you go `up`?

Comment: It's likely that you can use the gdb Python API [Python API (Debugging with GDB)](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html#Python-API) (or the machine-readable API [GDB/MI (Debugging with GDB)](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html))

Comment: See also [Parsing gdb.execute output with python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839639/parsing-gdb-execute-output-with-python) ?